# DataAnnotations validation adding `@` to RegularExpression

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

How do I add to accept `@` along with the RegularExpression I have below?

```
[StringLength(250)]
[RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-\.]*|^$", 
ErrorMessage = "DomainName may only contain letters (a-z), digits (0-9), hypens (-) and dots (.), and must start with a letter or digit")]
public string DomainName{ get; set; }
```

Comment: `@"[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9@.-]*|^$"`

Comment: sorry, did not work, tried to enter the `@` but it does not accept

Comment: Do you mean you entered just `@` alone? Then it won't work. You have a rule: *must start with a letter or digit*. Is it still valid? If not, you need to add `@` to the first character class, too: `@"[A-Za-z0-9@][A-Za-z0-9@.-]*|^$"`

Comment: i have entered something like this, `noreply@abc.com`

Comment: Have a look at [`^([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9@.-]*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/hT3wV0/1) - it should work for you.

Comment: paste that as answer  i will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9@.-]*)?$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hT3wV0/1)

Here is the regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9@.-]*)?` - 1 or 0 (due to `?` greedy quantifier) occurrence of...

  - `[A-Za-z0-9]` - one ASCII letter followed by...
  - `[A-Za-z0-9@.-]*` - 0 or more characters that are either ASCII letters or digits or literal `@`/`.`/`-` symbols.
- `$` end of string.

So, the main points are:

- adding the `@` into the second character class
- turning the whole expression into an optional group `(...)?` (it can also be a non-capturing group, BTW: `(?:...)?`)
- removing unnecessary escape symbols from the character class (if `-` is at the start/end of the character class, or as in your regex after a valid range, it does not require escaping).

Comment: Sorry, had to wait till my children go to bed. All explanations added.